# GCC is warning that field is used uninitialized

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I am bit banging I²C on an Atmel ATtiny85, which does not have a lot of resources.
Thus I have written my own implementation for the RTC module DS1307 in C++.
My class definition is as follows:

```
class DS1307 {
public:
    DS1307();
    ~DS1307() = default;
    uint8_t getSeconds();
private:
    I2c i2c;
    const uint8_t address = 0b1101000; // Datasheet
};
```

And the corresponding constructor implementation is:

```
#include "DS1307.h"

DS1307::DS1307(): i2c(address) {
}
```

When trying to compile this, the compiler complains that:

```
src/DS1307.cpp: In member function 'DS1307::DS1307()':
src/DS1307.cpp:7:29: warning: 'this_4(D)->address' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
 DS1307::DS1307(): i2c(address) {
                 ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

Why?
I am not doubting the correctness of GCC, but I thought that this was how you should initialize private fields.
The `I2c` class takes a `uint8_t` as the only argument for the constructor.

Comment: Why not making `address` a static member?

Comment: Making `address` a static member fixes the warning, thanks.
However, why does it?

Comment: Read *initialization order* from [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Data members are initialized in order of declaration in the class, so `i2c` is constructed taking indeterminate value of `address` as first, then value `0b1101000` is assigned to `address`. You can reorder data members to get proper behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: because initialization lists are evaluated with the same order as the members appear in the class. You may try swapping the two declaration lines, having address declared before I2C.

Also, making address static or using a preprocessor directive to define it would be more efficient on such a tiny device.